# How can I stop macro from ungrouping and hiding rows on its own

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using the code below to sort a spreadsheet with various subtotals. On  5 out of 6 spreadsheets it works as expected. On the 6th spreadsheet I have encountered a problem with Excel ungrouping one row from a sub group.  In the example below row 435 is removed from the rest of the group and row 436 has its height reduced to 0.  I have looked at every cell in rows  435 and 436 and each matches the other rows in the group.  After speaking with the users who would manually record a sorting macro they told me it sometimes happens to their spreadsheets as well.  this macro works for the first 27 groups it has to sort. The subgroup I am having a problem with has 95 rows, other groups that have more rows do not have a problem.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and has anyone figured out how to deal with it?

The code I am using is below.

```
Sub mcrFindSortGroup()

Dim strFirstRow As String
Dim strLastRow As String
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim strColumn As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

    Sheets("DCL Descriptions").Select
    Range("H2:H2").Select

strColumn = ActiveCell
strColumn = strColumn - 1

    Sheets("Sku Selling").Select

Columns("C:C").Select

For Each c In Range("DCL")
If c = "" Then GoTo DoneMsg

Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select

    Range("C1:C15000").Activate
    Selection.Find(What:=c, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

strFirstRow = ActiveCell.Row

Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Select
If Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 2) <> Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2) Then
strLastRow = ActiveCell.Row

GoTo SkipSort

End If

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

strLastRow = ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
strLastRow = ActiveCell.Row

RowCount = (strLastRow - strFirstRow) + 1

    Rows(strFirstRow & ":" & strLastRow).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sku Selling").Sort.SortFields.Clear

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sku Selling").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ActiveCell _
    .Offset(0, strColumn).Range("A" & 1 & ":A" & RowCount) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sku Selling").Sort
        .SetRange ActiveCell.Range("A" & 1 & ":ZZ" & RowCount)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
        End With

SkipSort: ' the group has only 1 sku and does not need to be sorted

    Next

DoneMsg:
MsgBox "Sorting Completed!", vbInformation, "Done"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
End Sub
```

These are before and after screen shots

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: what is Range("DCL") in the first for loop? FYI, you can upload screenshot to dropbox or similar place and post a link here.

Comment: DCL is a list of numbers relevant to each report. In this scenario each DCL number starts with 226 then a 2 digit class number and finally a 2 digit line number so I wind up with 2260101, 2260102 2260103, 2260201, 2260202 etc.

Comment: http://imgur.com/sq69De3,FWeKgpX#1 - link to before image

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/sq69De3.png - link to second image

Comment: Perhaps you should use Range variables for the "**Selection.Find**" and skip if it's **Nothing**. It is very hard for us to trace when you use ActiveCell so extensive and we don't have the workbook. You should put in `Debug.Print` lines here and there to help yourself troubleshoot.

Comment: I finally figured it out! I changed         .Header = xlGuess to         .Header = xlNo I'm not sure why it was interpreting the rows above as header but by explicitly stating the group had no headers seems to have taken care of the problem.